# Почему значение свойства counter записывается в форме крокозябр в файл?

Tags: java, кодировка, сериализация

```
import java.io.*;

/* 
OutputToConsole
*/
public class Solution {
    public static String greeting = "Hello world";

    /**
     * OutputToConsole is the inner base class for improving your attentiveness.
     * An OutputToConsole object encapsulates the information needed
     * for the displaying [greeting] variable to the console.
     * @author JavaRush
     */
    public static class OutputToConsole implements Externalizable {
        private int counter;

        /**
         * @param out A stream for an externalization
         * @throws java.io.IOException
         */
        @Override
        public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException {
            out.writeInt(counter);
        }

        /**
         * @param in A stream for a de-externalization
         * @throws java.io.IOException
         * @throws ClassNotFoundException
         */
        @Override
        public void readExternal(ObjectInput in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
            counter = in.readInt();
        }

        /**
         * Class constructor specifying fake private field [i].
         */
        public OutputToConsole(int counter) {
            this.counter = counter;
        }

        /**
         * Prints greeting message to console counter times.
         */
        public void printMessage() {
            for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
                System.out.println(greeting);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        OutputToConsole outPutConsole = new OutputToConsole(5);
        ObjectOutput objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("c:\\1.txt"));
        outPutConsole.writeExternal(objectOutput);
        objectOutput.close();
        ObjectInput objectInput = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("c:\\1.txt"));
        outPutConsole.readExternal(objectInput);
        objectInput.close();
        outPutConsole.printMessage();
    }
}
```

не понятно почему в файл пишутся крокозябры или это и есть значение свойства counter представленного в байтовом формате?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Классы `ObjectOutput` и `ObjectInput` предназначены для записи не текстовых файлов, а данных разных типов, включая объектные типы, в т. ч. строки и маччивы, в компактном двоичном формате. Эти файлы предназначены не для чтения глазами, а для восстановления записанных в них объектов. Когда при вызове `writeExternal` туда записывается значение счетчика, фактически в файл записывается служебная информация, необходимая для идентификации типа данных при чтении, и двоичное содержимое переменной (тип `int` -- 4 байта). Вы можете посмотреть содержимое файла каким-нибудь шестнадцетиричным редактором и увидите там несколько байт этой самой служебной информации и 4 байта, содержащие 32-разрядное число 5: `00 00 00 05`.

Answer (score 1):

`ObjectOutput` пишет данные так, чтобы `ObjectInput` мог их прочитать.

Для сохранения объекта может java может записать:

- протокол сериализации
- версию сериализации
- длину имени класса
- имя класса
- и много ещё служебной информации

Подробнее с разбором сериализации объектов можно прочитать [статью на хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/60317/)

---

Если вам нужен человеко-читаемый формат то используйте обычные потоки (`InputStream` и `OutputStream`). Записываете данные в определенном порядки и в том же порядке их читаете. Либо же можно сохранять данные в `JSON`, `XML` форматах